# Tabs in thew new GUI Builder

Tags: codenameone

I can't seem to find the Tabs component in the new GUI Builder. I remember it was available in the old one. I know that I can hard code the Tabs but I would prefer to do it inside the GUI Builder and keep all containers in one class. Am I missing something. Do I need to do something with a CustomComponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were too many bugs in the tabs so we disabled support as a temporary workaround. I suggest filing an issue and we'll try to restore them although I'm not sure if it will make it in time for 4.0.